# I want to copy data in a CSV file to SQL SERVER using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I am trying out something new is standalone application development using C#. I want to copy data in a CSV file to an SQL Server database, but it seems to something else.I have been on this problem for a whole day.Please somebody should help me out.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@filePath);
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] value = line.Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;

        foreach (string dc in value)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
        }

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            if (value.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = value;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "receipts";
            foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                //MessageBox.Show(column.ToString());
            }
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            bulkCopy.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Please what is the problem with my code?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't know, what is the problem? Do you get an error? Unexpected results? Or something different altogether?

Comment: it doesn't throw any error or exception. It just does nothing

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Does `dt` contain anything ? Does the *file* contain anything Try debugging your code *first*, then post a specific question in SO. There are any number of things that can be wrong, including posting to the wrong database or reading an empty file

Comment: I have done the debugging, the file contains something, the dt contains something. I just don't know

Comment: And? Does `bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);` execute correctly? Are you writing to the correct server/database? What does the `receipts` table contain?

Comment: I think it is from the columnmapping. Everything works till there

Comment: The receipt table is the table that will be populated from the CSV. the column names are `fullname`, `state`, `regno`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem, everything is working perfect! Sorry to post the answer late. What I did was to use for loop to read data from the datatable and insert it into the database.

Here is the code;

```
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@filePath);
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] value = line.Split(',');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row;

            foreach (string dc in value)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
            }

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                if (value.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
                {
                    row = dt.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = value;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }

            dgv.DataSource = dt;

            conn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [receipts] ([fullname], [state], [regno], [dept], [year], [session], [amount], [date], [faculty], [bank], [jamb]) VALUES('" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][3].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][5].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][6].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][7].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][8].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][9].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][10].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][11].ToString() + "', '" + dt.Rows[i][4].ToString() + "')", conn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            conn.Close();
```